# how it is different to use an iSCSI-connected disk than for example an SMB file share?

Tags: windows, smb, iscsi

How it is different to use an iSCSI-connected disk than for example an SMB file share?
Also what kind of use an iSCSI-connected disk is good for and what are the examples in which situations an SMB share would be more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

The difference for you is very easy to explain:
When using [iSCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iscsi), the access is at block level. This means, your OS request Block 32543, and gets back the raw data. The client OS manages filesystem, permission etc.
Only one Client can access a iSCSI Volume at the same time for read/write. Therefore it's faster in most cases, as there is less overhead.
When using [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block), the server manages the filesystem and permissions. Several clients can read the same files at the same time. The client doesn't know wheter it's EXT4, NTFS or Reiserfs.

Comment: To be precise: it is not true that multiple clients cannot access a single volume at the block level at the same time. There are special [clustered file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system) for this.

Comment: And what kind of use an iSCSI-connected disk is good for?

Comment: Please mark a solution.